# Подскажите как получить первый ответ в цикле for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, dict

Всем привет, у меня возникла ситуация. Мне нужно получить результаты первого цикла. У меня есть данные список словарей:

```
"poolList": [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "awesome.1@stratum.slushpool.com",
    "statusInfo": {},
    "additionalInfo": {
    "displayUrl": "stratum.slushpool.com:3333",
    "worker": "name_0"
    },
    "priorityInfo": {},
    "progressInfo": {},
    "coinName": "Bitcoin (BTC)",
    "minerID": 100000,
    "minerName": "S17",
    "canRemove": false,
    "canDisable": true,
    "canEnable": true,
    "canPrioritize": true
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name_1",
    "statusInfo": {},
    "additionalInfo": {
    "displayUrl": "stratum.slushpool.com:3333",
    "worker": "123456"
    },
    "priorityInfo": {},
    "progressInfo": {},
    "coinName": "",
    "minerID": 1000000001,
    "minerName": "",
    "canRemove": false,
    "canDisable": true,
    "canEnable": true,
    "canPrioritize": true
    }
    ]
....
```

И вот мой код цикл:

```
for pool in _minerList['poolList']:
            dict_miner['Worker'] = pool['additionalInfo']['worker']
```

я тут создаю словарь и обращаюсь. В итоге он мне выдает последний результат цикла а мне надо первый. Он выдал информацию где id 1 а мне нужно записать информацию из id 0.

Если будет не понятно то скину побольше часть кода.

Comment: зачем вам цикл, если нужен первый элемент? просто получите первый элемент `_minerList['poolList'][0]`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin У большой список и это часть информации которая нужна. Мне нужна информация у worker. Они везде разные и нужна информация у id 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может я не совсем правильно понял, но вроде тебе не нужен цикл и достаточно указать следующее:

```py
dict_miner['Worker'] = _minerList['poolList'][0]['additionalInfo']['worker']
```

Или же ты просто можешь делать break после первой же итерации:

```py
for pool in _minerList['poolList']:
            dict_miner['Worker'] = pool['additionalInfo']['worker']
            break
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range:(

Comment: break помог. Спасибо